# clear the python output stream

Tags: python, input, user-input

So I'm trying to code an assassin game generator but to do so, after it shows the player who their target is, it needs to clear the output stream.

I figured out that you have to manually clear it in Pycharm, so I decided to use the `os.system("cls")` method and open the python terminal:

```
import random
import sys
import time
import os

#Creating the players

np = input("How many players do you want to set? ")
np = int(np)

players = []
enemies = []

for player in range(1, np+1):
    player = str(player)
    x = (input("Player #" + player + ": "))
    x = str(x)
    x = x.title()
    players.append(x)
    enemies.append(x)


random.shuffle(players)
enemies = players.copy()
enemies.insert(0, enemies.pop(-1))

picked = []

def clear():
    os.system("cls")

print("Loading players and targets:")
time.sleep(2)
print("\n")

for p in range(np):
    r = random.randrange(np)
    while players[r] in picked:
        r = random.randrange(np)
    input("\033[1m" + players[r] + ", your target is: ")
    input("\033[31;1;4m" + enemies[r] + "\033[0m (Press Enter to continue)")
    picked.append(players[r])
    clear()
    print("\n")
```

I input the number of players, but when I input the first name, it gives me the following error:

```
How many players do you want to set? 5
Player #1: Bob
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bob\PycharmProjects\test\assassins.py", line 15, in <module>
    x = (input("Player #" + player + ": "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Bob' is not defined
```

I've tried to change a lot of different things but none work.

Version: Python 3.4

Comment: The line `x = str(x)` is redundant as input() always returns a string in python 3

Comment: I put it to see if that was the problem

Comment: While you say that you are using Python 3.4, perhaps PyCharm is using a version of Python 2. Try changing `input` on line 15 to `raw_input` to see what happens.

Comment: it tells me that "raw_input" is not defined (it's python 3.4)

Comment: Well then, I see that there is no reason why it shouldn't be working with the code you have provided.

Comment: Did you try to run it?

Comment: Using Python 3.6, I did. And it worked as expected.

Comment: Just tried it using python 3.6.0, doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running it in Terminal or PyCharm? They could be using different versions of Python.